# Scala: Can't subclass abstract generic superclass

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, abstract

I am trying to return a subclass of an abstract generic class in Scala but it won't compile. I get **Expression of type A doesn't conform to to expected type B**. 
here is the code I am using:

```
abstract class AA[T](val var1: String){
  def doSomething(): T;
}
class BB(override val var1: String) extends AA[Int](var1){
  override def doSomething(): Int = {
    return 5
  }
}

object Factory {
  def create(v: String) : AA[Any] = {
  return new BB("5") // this is the error
  }
}
```

What should be the signature of ***create()***?

Thanks

Comment: unrelated to your issue, but note that you don't need `return` and don't need semicolons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BB` extends `AA[Int]` but `Factory.create` claims to return an `AA[Any]`. You can fix this by making `AA` covariant in `T`:

```
abstract class AA[+T](val var1: String){
  def doSomething(): T
}
```